# Coordinate-Free Definition of Trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, trace

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}$

I am reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) on the trace operator. The section titled *Coordinate-Free Definition* defines the trace as follows.

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and define a bilinear map $f:V\times V^*\to F$ as $f(v, \omega)=\omega(v)$ for all $(v, \omega)\in V\times V^*$. This maps induces a unique linear map $\tr:V\otimes V^*\to F$.
>
> Since $\text{End}(V)$ has a canonical isomorphism with $V\otimes V^*$, we have now a notion of trace of a linear operator on $V$.

**The Question:** The second paragraph of the section in the article says that

> *This also clarifies why $\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$*.

I can't see how $\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$ follows from this definition at all.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: There is actually a sketched proof on the wiki page. Have you read it? Do you need some clarification of any specific detail there?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Somehow I was unable to notice that a proof was outlined. I kind of filtered that out as something unnecessary for my purpose.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To understand the trace, it is good to spell out the isomorphism between $End(V)$ and $V\otimes V^*$:
$$V\otimes V^*\to End(V): v\otimes\omega \mapsto (x\mapsto \omega(x)v).$$

Under this isomorphism, composition of endomorphisms becomes
$$(V\otimes V^*) \times (V\otimes V^*) \to V\otimes V^*: (v_2\otimes\omega_2, v_1\otimes \omega_1)\mapsto \omega_2(v_1)\cdot v_2\otimes \omega_1.$$

Taking the trace of this composition, one gets $\omega_2(v_1)\omega_1(v_2)$.  It is then easy to see that the trace of $v_2\otimes\omega_2\circ v_1\otimes \omega_1$ is the same as that of $v_1\otimes\omega_1\circ v_2\otimes \omega_2$.